# Python regular expression to split paragraphs

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text, split

How would one write a regular expression to use in Python to split paragraphs?

A paragraph is defined by two line breaks (\n). But one can have any amount of spaces/tabs together with the line breaks, and it still should be considered as a paragraph.

I am using Python, so the solution can use Python's [regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) which is extended. (can make use of `(?P...)` stuff)

#### Examples:

```
the_str = 'paragraph1\n\nparagraph2'
# Splitting should yield ['paragraph1', 'paragraph2']

the_str = 'p1\n\t\np2\t\n\tstill p2\t   \n     \n\tp3'
# Should yield ['p1', 'p2\t\n\tstill p2', 'p3']

the_str = 'p1\n\n\n\tp2'
# Should yield ['p1', '\n\tp2']
```

The best I could come with is: `r'[ \t\r\f\v]*\n[ \t\r\f\v]*\n[ \t\r\f\v]*'`, i.e.

```
import re
paragraphs = re.split(r'[ \t\r\f\v]*\n[ \t\r\f\v]*\n[ \t\r\f\v]*', the_str)
```

But that is ugly. Is there anything better?

#### Suggestions rejected:

`r'\s*?\n\s*?\n\s*?'` -> That would make example 2 and 3 fail, since `\s` includes `\n`, so it would allow paragraph breaks with more than 2 `\n`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no nice way to write "space but not a newline".

I think the best you can do is add some space with the `x` modifier and try to factor out the ugliness a bit, but that's questionable: `(?x)  (?: [ \t\r\f\v]*? \n ){2}  [ \t\r\f\v]*?`

You could also try creating a subrule just for the character class and interpolating it three times.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a regexp, but it is really elegant:

```
from itertools import groupby

def paragraph(lines):
    for group_separator, line_iteration in groupby(lines.splitlines(True), key = str.isspace):
        if not group_separator:
            yield ''.join(line_iteration)

for p in paragraph('p1\n\t\np2\t\n\tstill p2\t   \n     \n\tp'):
    print repr(p)

'p1\n'
'p2\t\n\tstill p2\t   \n'
'\tp3'
```

It's up to you to strip the output as you need it of course.

It was inspired by the famous "Python Cookbook" ;-)

Comment: Neat solution. What's `str_isspace`?

Comment: A typo :-) You should read str.isspace which a the method isspace() from the object string. It will be called to determine if something is a space, and will group object according to that. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You may be trying to deduce the structure of a document in plain test and doing what [docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/) does.

You might be able to simply use the [Docutils parser](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/dev/hacking.html#parsing-the-document) rather than roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same, but using non-greedy quantifiers and taking advantage of the whitespace sequence.

```
\s*?\n\s*?\n\s*?
```

Comment: that would make example 2 fail, because \s includes \n.