# Python regex, conditional searching

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split this sentence

```
"Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot " \
"for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this " \
"isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't."
```

Into list of below.

```
Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it.
Did he mind?
Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't.
In any case, this isn't true...
Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't.
```

Code:

```
print re.findall('([A-Z]+[^.].*?[a-z.][.?!] )[^a-z]',text)
```

Output:

```
['Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid
 a lot for it. ', "Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. "]
```

K gud, but it missed some, is there a way to tell Python since last [^a-z] isn't part of my group, pls continue searching from there.

**EDIT:**

This was achieved through forward look ahead regex as mentioned by @sputnick.

```
print re.findall('([A-Z]+[^.].*?[a-z.][.?!] )(?=[^a-z])',text)
```

Output:

```
['Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid
 a lot for it. ', 'Did he mind? ', "Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. "
, "In any case, this isn't true... "]
```

But we still need the last sentence. Any ideas?

Comment: related: [Python - RegEx for splitting text into sentences (sentence-tokenizing)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25735644/4279).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
print re.findall('([A-Z]+[^.].*?[a-z.][.?!] )(?=[^a-z])',text)
```

using *positive look-ahead* regex technique, check http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: wow, regex are awesome, works perfect. Thx @sputnick. What is `?=` actually meant for?

Comment: This is the syntax for _positive look-ahead_, check the added link in my answer

Comment: nice tutorial at the link, could there be a way also to include the last sentence saying exclude looking after the dot for a space and [^a-z] it its end of file. Something like word boundaries

Answer (score 1):

```
(.+?)(?<=(?<![A-Z][a-z])(?<![a-z]\.[a-z])(?:\.|\?)(?=\s|$))
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the capture or groups.Use `re.findall`.

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/45

Answer (score 0):

Finally

```
 print re.findall('[A-Z]+[^.].*?[a-z.][.?!] (?=[^a-z])|.*.$',text)
```

Above works perfect as needed. Includes the last sentence. But I have no idea why `|.*.$` worked pls help me understand.

Output:

```
['Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid
 a lot for it. ', 'Did he mind? ', "Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. "
, "In any case, this isn't true... ", "Well, with a probability of .9 
it isn't."]
```

Comment: There is no space at the end: `re.findall('[A-Z]+[^.].*?[a-z.][.?!](?: (?=[^a-z])|$)', text)`