# Accurately splitting sentences

Tags: python, parsing, nlp

My program takes a text file and splits each sentence into a list using `split('.')` meaning that it will split when it registers a full stop however it can be inaccurate.

## For Example

```
str='i love carpets. In fact i own 2.4 km of the stuff.'
```

### Output

`listOfSentences = ['i love carpets', 'in fact i own 2', '4 km of the stuff']`

### Desired Output

```
 listOfSentences = ['i love carpets', 'in fact i own 2.4 km of the stuff']
```

My question is: **How do I split the end of sentences and not at every full stop.**

Comment: listOfSentences = file.split(".")

Comment: Splitting into sentences is a non-trivial task. Maybe you can try Natural Language Toolkit. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences) to the similar question.

Comment: Indeed, also consider abbreviations, e.g. like this one. Tokenisation and sentence splitting is quite an interesting, albeit under-appreciated, task in. NLTK surely has tokenisation and sentence splitting functions. For a specialized solution you can also consider using _ucto_ with python-ucto (https://github.com/proycon/ucto , https://github.com/proycon/python-ucto), which can tokenize and sentence split various languages.  [_disclaimer_: I am the author of ucto]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you have sentences both ending with "." and ". ", you can try regex:

```
import re

text = "your text here. i.e. something."
sentences = re.split(r'(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s', text)
```

source: [Python - RegEx for splitting text into sentences (sentence-tokenizing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735644/python-regex-for-splitting-text-into-sentences-sentence-tokenizing)

Comment: What if the sentence has `Mr.` (or `i.e.`) in it?  Your own example yields `["your text here", "i.e", "something."]`.

Answer (score 3):

Any regex based approach cannot handle cases like *"I saw Mr. Smith."*, and adding hacks for those cases is not scalable.  As user *est* has commented, any serious implementation uses data.

If you need to handle English only then spaCy is better than NLTK:

```
from spacy.en import English
en = English()
doc = en(u'i love carpets. In fact i own 2.4 km of the stuff.')
for s in list(doc.sents):
    print s.string
```

Update: spaCy now supports many languages.

Comment: AFAIK there are no up-to-date quantitative evaluations about sentence splitting. Regarding your statement that spacy is better than nltk for English: I just experience the opposite, i.e., while I switched to spacy almost completely, I figured that its sentence splitting performance is not as good as the performance of nltk punkt for English news articles.

Comment: You may be right, I can't remember why exactly I asserted that, even though I would still bet it's true.

Comment: NLTK was designed as an academic library and is not robust enough for a production environment (issues like scalability, speed, even the architecture). Spacy is designed for production environments and has better model management. You can find a good comparison here: https://www.activestate.com/blog/natural-language-processing-nltk-vs-spacy/

Answer (score 0):

I found https://github.com/fnl/syntok/ to be quite good, actually the best from all the popular ones. Specifically, I tested nltk (punkt), spacy, and syntok on English news articles.

```
import syntok.segmenter as segmenter

document = "some text. some more text"

for paragraph in segmenter.analyze(document):
    for sentence in paragraph:
        for token in sentence:
            # exactly reproduce the input
            # and do not remove "imperfections"
            print(token.spacing, token.value, sep='', end='')
    print("\n")  # reinsert paragraph separators
```

Answer (score -1):

Not splitting at numbers can be done using the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) function of the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'i love carpets. In fact i own 2.4 km of the stuff.'
>>> re.split(r'\.[^0-9]', s)
['i love carpets', 'In fact i own 2.4 km of the stuff.']
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is to split on a dot followed by a space as:

```
>>> s = 'i love carpets. In fact i own 2.4 km of the stuff.'
>>> s.split('. ')
['i love carpets', 'In fact i own 2.4 km of the stuff.']
```

Comment: okay but what if it there was a case where there wasn't a space after for example: `population of 142,100,.[2] falling to 142,065 at the 2011 Census` the [2] stops this from working

Comment: Also what about abbreviations followed by dot? And for example question marks, exclamation marks, etc.?

Comment: You are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences