# Split paragraph into sentences with Python3

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, split

I'm programming a telegram Bot helping me learn German.

Instead of translating the entire paragraph, I would like to translate step by step each sentence, with its translation following immediately, so that I can confront words and learn, instead of keep scrolling up and down.

I'm a regex newbie.

I would like to know if there exist such one.

My text to split into sentences could be like this:

```
This is a sentence.
This is another. And here one another, same line, starting with space.
this sentence starts with lowercase letter.
Here is a site you may know: google.com.
```

I would like to get an array containing something like (I'm here writing one element of the array per row you are seeing now):

```
This is a sentence.
This is another. 
And here one another,same line, starting with space.
this sentence starts with lowercase letter.
Here is a site you may know: google.com.
```

Thanks indeed in advance.

Comment: Of course this has been asked before. Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735644/python-regex-for-splitting-text-into-sentences-sentence-tokenizing) help?

Comment: Even natural language parsing will have trouble finding sentences. Given that, It's not something regex can do. Reason ? Regex parses characters, not words, phrases, sentence structure, nor anything to do with a language, it's usage, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely better handled with `nltk` ([having installed it correctly](http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-i-getting-started-with-nltk), that is):

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

string = "This is a sentence. This is another. And here one another, same line, starting with space. this sentence starts with lowercase letter. Here is a site you may know: google.com."

sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(string)
print(sent_tokenize_list)
# ['This is a sentence.', 'This is another.', 'And here one another, same line, starting with space.', 'this sentence starts with lowercase letter.', 'Here is a site you may know: google.com.']
```