# GRU Language Model not Training Properly

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I’ve tried reimplementing a simple GRU language model using just a GRU and a linear layer (the full code is also at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/gru-language-model-not-training-properly):

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_size, hidden_size, num_layers):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

        # Initialize the embedding layer with the 
        # - size of input (i.e. no. of words in input vocab)
        # - no. of hidden nodes in the embedding layer
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, padding_idx=0)

        # Initialize the GRU with the 
        # - size of the input (i.e. embedding layer)
        # - size of the hidden layer 
        self.gru = nn.GRU(embedding_size, hidden_size, num_layers)

        # Initialize the "classifier" layer to map the RNN outputs
        # to the vocabulary. Remember we need to -1 because the 
        # vectorized sentence we left out one token for both x and y:
        # - size of hidden_size of the GRU output.
        # - size of vocabulary
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, inputs, use_softmax=False, hidden=None):
        # Look up for the embeddings for the input word indices.
        embedded = self.embedding(inputs)
        # Put the embedded inputs into the GRU.
        output, hidden = self.gru(embedded, hidden)

        # Matrix manipulation magic.
        batch_size, sequence_len, hidden_size = output.shape
        # Technically, linear layer takes a 2-D matrix as input, so more manipulation...
        output = output.contiguous().view(batch_size * sequence_len, hidden_size)
        # Put it through the classifier
        # And reshape it to [batch_size x sequence_len x vocab_size]
        output = self.classifier(output).view(batch_size, sequence_len, -1)

        return (F.softmax(output,dim=2), hidden) if use_softmax else (output, hidden)


    def generate(self, max_len, temperature=1.0):
        pass
```

And the training routine:

```
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

# Set the hidden_size of the GRU 
embed_size = 100
hidden_size = 100
num_layers = 1

# Setup the data.
batch_size=50
kilgariff_data = KilgariffDataset(tokenized_text)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=kilgariff_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=kilgariff_data.vocab.token2id['<pad>'], size_average=True)
model = Generator(len(kilgariff_data.vocab), embed_size, hidden_size, num_layers).to(device)

learning_rate = 0.003
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

#model = nn.DataParallel(model)

losses = []

def train(num_epochs, dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer):
    plt.ion()
    for _e in range(num_epochs):
        for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
            x = batch['x'].to(device)
            x_len = batch['x_len'].to(device)
            y = batch['y'].to(device)
            # Zero gradient.
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # Feed forward. 
            output, hidden = model(x, use_softmax=True)
            # Compute loss:
            # Shape of the `output` is [batch_size x sequence_len x vocab_size]
            # Shape of `y` is [batch_size x sequence_len]
            # CrossEntropyLoss expects `output` to be [batch_size x vocab_size x sequence_len]

            _, prediction = torch.max(output, dim=2)
            loss = criterion(output.permute(0, 2, 1), y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            losses.append(loss.float().data)

            clear_output(wait=True)
            plt.plot(losses)
            plt.pause(0.05)


train(50, dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer)

#learning_rate = 0.05
#optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
#train(4, dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer)
```

But when the model is predicting, we see that it’s only predicting “the” and comma “,”.

**Anyone spot something wrong with my code? Or hyperparameters?**

The full code:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


# IPython candies...
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.core.display import HTML

from IPython.display import clear_output


# In[2]:


import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

import pandas as pd

from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

import torch
from torch import nn, optim, tensor, autograd
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pack_padded_sequence, pad_packed_sequence

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'


# In[3]:


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(12, 8)})


torch.manual_seed(42)


# In[4]:


try: # Use the default NLTK tokenizer.
    from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize 
    # Testing whether it works. 
    # Sometimes it doesn't work on some machines because of setup issues.
    word_tokenize(sent_tokenize("This is a foobar sentence. Yes it is.")[0])
except: # Use a naive sentence tokenizer and toktok.
    import re
    from nltk.tokenize import ToktokTokenizer
    # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736515/610569
    sent_tokenize = lambda x: re.split(r'(?<=[^A-Z].[.?]) +(?=[A-Z])', x)
    # Use the toktok tokenizer that requires no dependencies.
    toktok = ToktokTokenizer()
    word_tokenize = word_tokenize = toktok.tokenize


# In[5]:


import os
import requests
import io #codecs


# Text version of https://kilgarriff.co.uk/Publications/2005-K-lineer.pdf
if os.path.isfile('language-never-random.txt'):
    with io.open('language-never-random.txt', encoding='utf8') as fin:
        text = fin.read()
else:
    url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alvations/53b01e4076573fea47c6057120bb017a/raw/b01ff96a5f76848450e648f35da6497ca9454e4a/language-never-random.txt"
    text = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf8')
    with io.open('language-never-random.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fout:
        fout.write(text)


# In[6]:


# Tokenize the text.
tokenized_text = [list(map(str.lower, word_tokenize(sent))) 
                  for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]


# In[7]:


class KilgariffDataset(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, texts):
        self.texts = texts

        # Initialize the vocab 
        special_tokens = {'<pad>': 0, '<unk>':1, '<s>':2, '</s>':3}
        self.vocab = Dictionary(texts)
        self.vocab.patch_with_special_tokens(special_tokens)

        # Keep track of the vocab size.
        self.vocab_size = len(self.vocab)

        # Keep track of how many data points.
        self._len = len(texts)

        # Find the longest text in the data.
        self.max_len = max(len(txt) for txt in texts) 

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        vectorized_sent = self.vectorize(self.texts[index])
        x_len = len(vectorized_sent)
        # To pad the sentence:
        # Pad left = 0; Pad right = max_len - len of sent.
        pad_dim = (0, self.max_len - len(vectorized_sent))
        vectorized_sent = F.pad(vectorized_sent, pad_dim, 'constant')
        return {'x':vectorized_sent[:-1], 
                'y':vectorized_sent[1:], 
                'x_len':x_len}

    def __len__(self):
        return self._len

    def vectorize(self, tokens, start_idx=2, end_idx=3):
        """
        :param tokens: Tokens that should be vectorized. 
        :type tokens: list(str)
        """
        # See https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.doc2idx 
        # Lets just cast list of indices into torch tensors directly =)

        vectorized_sent = [start_idx] + self.vocab.doc2idx(tokens) + [end_idx]
        return torch.tensor(vectorized_sent)

    def unvectorize(self, indices):
        """
        :param indices: Converts the indices back to tokens.
        :type tokens: list(int)
        """
        return [self.vocab[i] for i in indices]


# In[8]:


kilgariff_data = KilgariffDataset(tokenized_text)
len(kilgariff_data.vocab)


# In[9]:


batch_size = 10
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=kilgariff_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

for data_dict in dataloader:
    # Sort indices of data in batch by lengths.
    sorted_indices = np.array(data_dict['x_len']).argsort()[::-1].tolist()
    data_batch = {name:_tensor[sorted_indices]
                  for name, _tensor in data_dict.items()}
    print(data_batch)
    break


# In[97]:


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_size, hidden_size, num_layers):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

        # Initialize the embedding layer with the 
        # - size of input (i.e. no. of words in input vocab)
        # - no. of hidden nodes in the embedding layer
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, padding_idx=0)

        # Initialize the GRU with the 
        # - size of the input (i.e. embedding layer)
        # - size of the hidden layer 
        self.gru = nn.GRU(embedding_size, hidden_size, num_layers)

        # Initialize the "classifier" layer to map the RNN outputs
        # to the vocabulary. Remember we need to -1 because the 
        # vectorized sentence we left out one token for both x and y:
        # - size of hidden_size of the GRU output.
        # - size of vocabulary
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, inputs, use_softmax=False, hidden=None):
        # Look up for the embeddings for the input word indices.
        embedded = self.embedding(inputs)
        # Put the embedded inputs into the GRU.
        output, hidden = self.gru(embedded, hidden)

        # Matrix manipulation magic.
        batch_size, sequence_len, hidden_size = output.shape
        # Technically, linear layer takes a 2-D matrix as input, so more manipulation...
        output = output.contiguous().view(batch_size * sequence_len, hidden_size)
        # Put it through the classifier
        # And reshape it to [batch_size x sequence_len x vocab_size]
        output = self.classifier(output).view(batch_size, sequence_len, -1)

        return (F.softmax(output,dim=2), hidden) if use_softmax else (output, hidden)


    def generate(self, max_len, temperature=1.0):
        pass


# In[98]:


# Set the hidden_size of the GRU 
embed_size = 12
hidden_size = 10
num_layers = 4

_encoder = Generator(len(kilgariff_data.vocab), embed_size, hidden_size, num_layers)


# In[99]:


# Take a batch.
_batch = next(iter(dataloader))
_inputs, _lengths = _batch['x'], _batch['x_len']
_targets = _batch['y']
max(_lengths)


# In[100]:


_output, _hidden = _encoder(_inputs)
print('Output sizes:\t', _output.shape)
print('Input sizes:\t', batch_size, kilgariff_data.max_len -1, len(kilgariff_data.vocab))
print('Target sizes:\t', _targets.shape)


# In[101]:


_, predicted_indices = torch.max(_output, dim=2)
print(predicted_indices.shape)
predicted_indices


# In[103]:


device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

# Set the hidden_size of the GRU 
embed_size = 100
hidden_size = 100
num_layers = 1

# Setup the data.
batch_size=50
kilgariff_data = KilgariffDataset(tokenized_text)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=kilgariff_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=kilgariff_data.vocab.token2id['<pad>'], size_average=True)
model = Generator(len(kilgariff_data.vocab), embed_size, hidden_size, num_layers).to(device)

learning_rate = 0.003
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

#model = nn.DataParallel(model)

losses = []

def train(num_epochs, dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer):
    plt.ion()
    for _e in range(num_epochs):
        for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
            x = batch['x'].to(device)
            x_len = batch['x_len'].to(device)
            y = batch['y'].to(device)
            # Zero gradient.
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # Feed forward. 
            output, hidden = model(x, use_softmax=True)
            # Compute loss:
            # Shape of the `output` is [batch_size x sequence_len x vocab_size]
            # Shape of `y` is [batch_size x sequence_len]
            # CrossEntropyLoss expects `output` to be [batch_size x vocab_size x sequence_len]

            _, prediction = torch.max(output, dim=2)
            loss = criterion(output.permute(0, 2, 1), y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            losses.append(loss.float().data)

            clear_output(wait=True)
            plt.plot(losses)
            plt.pause(0.05)


train(50, dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer)

#learning_rate = 0.05
#optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
#train(4, dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer)


# In[ ]:


list(kilgariff_data.vocab.items())


# In[105]:


start_token = '<s>'
hidden_state = None
max_len = 20
temperature=0.8

i = 0

while start_token not in ['</s>', '<pad>'] and i < max_len:
    i += 1
    start_state = torch.tensor(kilgariff_data.vocab.token2id[start_token]).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
    model.embedding(start_state)
    output, hidden_state = model.gru(model.embedding(start_state), hidden_state)

    batch_size, sequence_len, hidden_size = output.shape
    output = output.contiguous().view(batch_size * sequence_len, hidden_size)

    output = model.classifier(output).view(batch_size, sequence_len, -1)
    _, prediction = torch.max(F.softmax(output, dim=2), dim=2)

    start_token = kilgariff_data.vocab[int(prediction.squeeze(0).squeeze(0))]

    print(start_token, end=' ')
```

Comment: Also asking on https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/gru-model-not-training-properly/39719

Answer (score 2):

I'm by no means a PyTorch expert, but that snippet looks fishy to me:

```
    # Put the embedded inputs into the GRU.
    output, hidden = self.gru(embedded, hidden)
    # Matrix manipulation magic.
    batch_size, sequence_len, hidden_size = output.shape
    # Technically, linear layer takes a 2-D matrix as input, so more manipulation...
    output = output.contiguous().view(batch_size * sequence_len, hidden_size)
```

- When `GRU` is not instantiated with `batch_first=True`, then the output shape is `(seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size)` -- not that `seq_len` and `batch_size` are flipped. For the view command it actually doesn't technically matter, but that's my main issue here.
- `view(batch_size * sequence_len, hidden_size)` doesn't look right at all. Say you start with a batch of size 32, but after that you have size of `32*seq_len`. Usually, only the output of the last step is used (or the average or the max over all steps)

Something like this should work:

```
    # Put the embedded inputs into the GRU.
    output, hidden = self.gru(embedded, hidden)
    # Not needed, just to show the true output shape order
    seq_len, batch_size, hidden_size = output.shape
    # Given the shape of output, this is the last step
    output = output[-1]
    # output.shape = (batch_size, hidden_size) <-- What you want
```

Two personal words of warning:

- `view()` is a dangerous command! PyTorch or any other framework only throws errors when the dimensions of the tensors do not match up. But just because the dimensions fit after `view()` does not mean the reshaping was done correctly, i.e., that the values are in the right spot of the output tensor. For example, if you have to flatten a shape `(seq_len, batch_size, hidden_size)` to `(batch_size, seq_len*hidden_size)`, you cannot simply do `view(batch_size, -1)`, but first have to do `transpose(1,0)` to get a shape of `(batch_size, seq_len, hidden_size)`. With out without `transpose()`, `view()` will work and the dimensions will be correct. But only with `transpose()`, the values are at the right position after `view()`
- Since this is such an easy mistake to make, I saw many examples on GitHub and such where in my opinion it's no done correctly. The problem is that the network often still learns something. In short, I'm not much more careful when looking and adopting code snippets and the `view()` command is in my opinion the biggest trap.

If it helps, here's the `forward` method of a GRU classifier network:

```
def forward(self, batch, method='last_step'):
    embeds = self.word_embeddings(batch)
    x = torch.transpose(embeds, 0, 1)
    x, self.hidden = self.gru(x, self.hidden)

    if method == 'last_step':
        x = x[-1]
    elif method == 'average_pooling':
        x = torch.sum(x, dim=0) / len(batch[0])
    elif method == 'max_pooling':
        x, _ = torch.max(x, dim=0)
    else:
        raise Exception('Unknown method.')
    # A series of Linear layers with ReLU and Dropout
    for l in self.linears:
        x = l(x)
    log_probs = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
    return log_probs
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

This line in `train()` should be

```
output, hidden = model(x, use_softmax=False)
```

Disable the `use_softmax` when you train, then the model should train properly and the training CE loss will decrease near 0.

See https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/gru-language-model