# Python Regex Sentence Finder-Want to Ignore "a.m."

Tags: python, regex

I am developing a regex to find sentences, and I would like to ignore abbreviations that cause the regex to terminate before the end of the sentence.  For example, I want to ignore "**a.m.**" so that it returns "**At 9:00 a.m. the store opens.**" instead of "**At 9:00 a.m.**"

```
def sentence_finder(x):
    RegexObject = re.compile(r'[A-Z].+?\b(?!a\.m\.\b)\w+[.?!](?!\S)')
    Variable = RegexObject.findall(x)
    return Variable
```

I get back the following when I run pytest:

```
def test_pass_Ignore_am():
>       assert DuplicateSentences.sentence_finder("At 9:00 a.m. the store opens.") == ["At 9:00 a.m. the store opens."]
E       AssertionError: assert ['At 9:00 a.m.'] == ['At 9:00 a.m...store opens.']
E         At index 0 diff: 'At 9:00 a.m.' != 'At 9:00 a.m. the store opens.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `[A-Z](?:a\.m\.|.)*?\w[.?!](?!\S)`, see https://regex101.com/r/78k0By/1

Comment: What about `p.m.` `e.g.` `Ave.` etc.? You should use a more universal rule other than only excluding `a.m.`

Comment: For previous work on a sentence finder you should check out my answer to [Using regular expression as a tokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63870746/using-regular-expression-as-a-tokenizer/63871635#63871635).  It worked perfectly on this [complex legal narrative](https://pastebin.com/y0XC3wig).

Comment: Try [`(?=[A-Z]).+?[.?!](?=\s*(?:[A-Z]|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/HR7Ij3/1), it should work for most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookbehind to check that after matching a dot, there is not `a.m.` before it.

```
[A-Z].*?\w[.?!](?<!\ba\.m\.)(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `[A-Z]` Match a char A-Z
- `.*?` Match 0+ times any char except a newline as least as possible
- `\w[.?!]` Match a word char followed by either `.` `?` or `!`
- `(?<!\ba\.m\.)` Negative lookbehind to assert that directly to the left is not `a.m.`
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ShtJsb/1)