# trying to split a sentence with regex expression

Tags: python, regex

So far this regex expression found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735644/python-regex-for-splitting-text-into-sentences-sentence-tokenizing) works nice in almost every contest i'm working with.

```
(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=[.?])\s
```

infect it's able to split properly even sentences like this one:

```
Mr. Daniel, who love cakes, is taking a trip to Nevada. Not gonna lie, i would go as well.
```

into:

```
Mr. Daniel, who love cakes, is taking a trip to Nevada.
Not gonna lie, i would go as well.
```

Unfortunately it doenst cover a case.
if i've, for example, a sentence like this:

```
C. Daniel, who love cakes, is taking a trip to Nevada. Not gonna lie, i would go as well.
```

this regex epression makes the split in three sub sentences:

```
C.
Daniel, who love cakes, is taking a trip to Nevada.
Not gonna lie, i would go as well.
```

Instead of:

```
C. Daniel, who love cakes, is taking a trip to Nevada.
Not gonna lie, i would go as well.
```

What we're missing is this specific case is when we find a match that has a single Uppercase Chart followed by a dot (.) we dont have to split.

I still dont know how to proper use regex so if you can tell me also why your answer would work will be much appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the pattern adding a negative lookbehind `(?<!\b[A-Z]\.)` to assert not an uppercase char followed by a `.` directly to the left.

I think you can also omit the dot after `\w.` as the dot matches any character except a newline.

```
(?<!\b[A-Z]\.)(?<!\w\.\w)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=[.?])\s
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QL5vvv/1)

Comment: Seems it's working! could you please just tell me why did u put a \b as well?

Comment: @costabrava In that case, the string can split when it ends on 2 uppercase chars. https://regex101.com/r/hmu10Q/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-regex based solution, you can use nltk here.

```
import nltk

txt_1 = "C. Daniel, who love cakes, is taking a trip to Nevada. Not gonna lie, i would go as well."

nltk.sent_tokenize(txt_1)

['C. Daniel, who love cakes, is taking a trip to Nevada.',
 'Not gonna lie, i would go as well.']

txt_2 = "Mr. Daniel, who love cakes, is taking a trip to Nevada. Not gonna lie, i would go as well."
nltk.sent_tokenize(txt_2)

['Mr. Daniel, who love cakes, is taking a trip to Nevada.',
 'Not gonna lie, i would go as well.']
```