# Wiki API - Parsing sentences from JSON extracts in JavaScript?

Tags: api, extract, wikipedia

Is there a way to have wiki display extracts in an array of sentences?

Or does anyone have any ideas other than using `string.split(".")` to parse?  There are cases where the sentence may include a `.` and I don't want to split if it occurs mid-sentence.

For example, `"The Eagles were No. 1 in the U.S. in 1970"` would be split into 4 sentences using `str.split()`, and that's not what I want.

Wiki must have some sort of determination of what defines a sentence as it works when you limit the number of existence in a call (they don't break a sentence on an in-line period). Is there a way to get them individually?

Looking for a solution in JavaScript to parse a JSON excerpt string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break up a paragraph by sentences in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474395/how-to-break-up-a-paragraph-by-sentences-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a work-around.  Using exsentences, I made 10 calls, each with one more sentence than the previous call.  I stored the results of each call in an array.  So when the 10 calls were complete, I had 10 strings, ranging from one sentence in position 0, up to 10 sentences in the 9th position.  Then I just iterated through the array, from 0 to length - 2, subtracting the string in the current position from the string at position [i + 1] (with string[i + 1].slice(string[i].length)), to get the nth string.